# Uploading DIRECTLY to AWS via React/NextJS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I've run through a few tutorials and managed to put together the following code to upload to AWS.  However, The workflow for this is a usual file upload i.e.

- User selects file from their machine
- File gets uploaded to our server
- File gets uploaded to AWS

I want to skip the middle part as our server is already hosted on AWS and having multiple users upload many items only for it to be copied over is going to increase costs in buckets.  Plus there is the issue of multiple progress bars for each upload and more.

How can I upload *directly* from the users machine *straight* to an AWS S3 Bucket??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a pre-signed url from your backend services.
Then use this pre-signed url to do a post directly from the browser to S3.

See :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html